# Write QgsPrintLayout content into docx file with pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer, layouts

I would like to know if it is possible to write a QgsPrintLayout object into a docx file, using PyQGIS. Initially, I was asked to write it in a PDF file, but now my client wants it in a docx file, so that they can change the file if they want.

The layout contains several maps, legends, text and tables.

I looked through the QgsLayoutExporter class, but there is nothing about writing to a docx file, and I have not found any example on the internet.

I believe Python can write a docx file (I never tried it). Is it possible to write into a docx file, with python, a layout content that was created with PyQGIS?

Comment: What do they want to change? There are PDF editors too, e. g. Scribus, as long as they do not want to edit text.

Comment: This is not negociable, I do not have a say in this. They do plan to edit text.

Comment: You could use Inkscape to convert the PDF to EMF that can be inserted into MS Word as editable vector graphic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end I used the library "python-docx".

I managed to create and fill text areas and tables. However, I did not have time to try loading images in the docx.